# @google-cloud/vision in one wakanda node worker

Tags: wakanda

I try to use @google-cloud/vision in wakanda
I first use the 'https' example of the documentation
with two files test.js and worker.js
All is nice.
If I just write one line in the "worker.js" file
var vision = requireNode('@google-cloud/vision');

nothing happens now
It seems like wakanda could not require '@google-cloud/vision'
I tried the same with threadify....without success
Did somebody already this nice feature "cloudwision" with wakanda ?

Answer (score 0):

I have not used with @google-cloud/vision with node worker. But I would recommend checking if you have the module placed in backend/modules properly.